# What is Best Process to develop Form with 15 fields, Specially using React JS, semantic UI with out Redux or any other else

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to create a long-form page that will have 5 fields per each page with `continue` button. What is best format for coding alignment especially in react js with functional components only.

I have 3 approaches in mind.

1. Keeping each page fields in different pages like page1, page2, page3 and then access in parent.
2. Keeping all fields in one file and accessing those using switch case by passing page numbers.
3. Keeping all fields in one page and loading all fields, but hiding some fields based on the page number.

If there is any other best standard approach that will reduce future maintenance, and fewer coding changes, with less duplicate code so... on please prescribe hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach according to me would be making a single `component` that will hold all the form values and conditionally render them on screen. What you can do is, create three `div`'s that will render conditionally like:

```
{ step === 1 && <div>{"Your form here"}</div>}
```

The best part of this approach is that you will have all the `form` data at single place. And then you can easily pass that data to an `API` and make a request.